# How to configure mapping programmatically?

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, persistent

Our Hibernate configuration mapping have been implemented programatically in `java`, not with `annotation` and not with `XML` mapping.

We have a mapping classes hierarchy that we're setting in the Hibernate Mappings instance when the context is initialized, for instance:

```
Mappings mappings = configuration.createMappings();
mappings.addClass(PersistentClass instance);
```

Now, the issue I'm facing with is quite simple but i don't find an example how to add it for our implementation.

Let's say that

we have 2 tables`A` and `B` with Many to one relation,
`A.type_id = B.id.` and i want to retrieve all records from `A` with the following condition:
`A.type_id = B.id and B.id = 4;`

How can i add the association (many to one) in my mapping object. `org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.`

Comment: what is asked in question Header and what is described in body are different. Correct

Answer (score 3):

The question is old, but maybe the answer help someone other.

The topic is to complex to be answered here. Unfortunately the Hibernate documentation does not contain a lot of information and even the source code itself is not documentated at all.

This blog post http://portofino.manydesigns.com/en/blog/configuring-hibernate-programmatically (and the second part of it) gives an overview of how to create the mapping programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480851/unsupportedoperationexception-the-application-must-supply-jdbc-connections)

Also note that .addclass does not work as easily as you think it should. You need a cfg.xml and hbm file combination.

Comment: Use Configuration#addAnnotatedClass() to get rid of the xml files.