# UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

If I dont set anything programmatically and just call `Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();` and use the hibernate.properties (as below) everything works just great. As soon as I try to provide username, password and connection url programmatically, I get a weird Exceptions, hinting at the hbm file. What am I missing ?

## This Works

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://myEC2/mCruiseOnServerDB?autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10
hsqldb.write_delay_millis=0
shutdown=true
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=mypwd
hibernate.connection.pool_size=2
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=300
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=120
```

## As per @Kshitij recommendation. Doing a mixed mode.

**The hibernate.properties** now is

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hsqldb.write_delay_millis=0
shutdown=true
hibernate.connection.pool_size=2
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
```

**The Code**

```
String connection = "jdbc:mysql://"
            + Globals.DBSERVER
            + "/mCruiseOnServerDB?autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10";
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration()   
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", connection)                                
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", Globals.DB_USER_NAME)     
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", Globals.DB_PASSWORD);
        configuration.configure();

        sessionFactory = configuration
                .buildSessionFactory(new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .buildServiceRegistry());
```

**The Exception**

I now get this exception, one for every `mapping resource` entry in my hbm file.

```
11 May 2013 08:46:31,969 1300 [main] FATAL ReadOnlyOperations  - Have chosen to ignore this runtime exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections, may be fatal, examine this carefully
11 May 2013 08:46:31,969 1300 [main] FATAL ReadOnlyOperations  - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
```

## Summary

If I use all `hibernate.properties` and no code (no .setProperty in code) everything works great. If I use part `hibernate.properties` and part code (server, username, password) I get errors for in the hbm for every mapping property.

I need someone to help me figure out what I am missing. It should be something really basic.

Comment: [Refer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211451/connection-cannot-be-null-when-hibernate-dialect-not-set)

Comment: I already have tried it, does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, just fixed the problem.

```
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry());
```

I was missing the

> > .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())

Learnings

1. configure() should be called **AFTER** setProperty
2. Use `hibernate.connection.url` and **NOT** `connection.url` if you use `hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect`
3. Set log4j property for hibernate logs to ALL, so that you can see more detailed issues
4. To get rid of the `WARN Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!`, you need to replace `http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/` in the **cfg.xml** and all **hbm** files too. Dont forget teh **hbm** files, they too use the same DTD.

Lastly, referred to this, to fix [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/564214/ORM/databases/Hibernate-configuration-connection-provider-hibernate). The last advice by `Bill Gorder` is superb.

```
private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory()    
        throws HibernateException {    
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();    
    configuration.configure();    
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()    
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())    
            .buildServiceRegistry();    
    return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);    
}
```

Comment: so are you mixing properties or adding all inside java file?

Comment: mixing, some in properties file, and some in java

Comment: I too had same problem .. I cant find the class `ServiceRegistryBuilder()` Which version of HIbernate it will work .  I am using Hibernate 3.x

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way will be load all properties from `hibernate.cfg.xml` or `hibernate.properties` and overwrite only the one required programmatically.

```
Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "xyz" );
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "password" );
```

Comment: I am now getting `10 May 2013 14:20:34,238 1196 [main] FATAL ReadOnlyOperations  - Have chosen to ignore this runtime exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections, may be fatal, examine this carefully
` 1 for every hbm file.

Comment: Basically non of the hbm file are loading after I made your change. So its still not complete.

Comment: have u set `hibernate.connection.url`? from your modified code it doesn't seems u have put that programmatically.

Comment: Yes, I did, just forgot to mention it.

Comment: also i see u have done `configuration.configure();` after set properties. U need to do it before setProperty. See how i have done it in the example i have shown above.

Comment: I tried it, did not work. I'll try again and report back exact error.

Comment: Exactly same exception, no change at all.

Comment: Sorry your suggestions did not work. .configure should also be called after setProperty.

Comment: @Siddharth from your answer it looks u did followed the suggestion I gave of using properties from config files as well as programmatically. In additon, .applySettings(..) did the trick for u. good it worked.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Your answer did give me food for thought. Just correct the configuration after the setProperties and I will happily upvote. Without .applySettings it just does not work. Also delete your comment on "before not after". Lets cleanup this SO post.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are setting the connection parameters (URL, username, passwords) programmatically you should make sure other conditions which would force the usage of JDBC connections at application startup are not present. I identified at least two:

1. Setting the **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto** property to any other value than "none" forces a connection to the DB at startup; to validate, create or update the DB schema...
2. If you are using C3P0 properties in your hibernate.cfg.xml or persistence.xml, this also forces the pooling manager to try too acquire connections from the DB at startup

In all these cases, since you forced the connections to the DB without also configuring the connection parameters you will receive various error (like the one you faced)...

In order to fix these error either disable the property (**hibernate.hbm2ddl**) or set the other properties also programmatically (**hibernate.c3p0.***)